# Error End of statement expected

Tags: vb.net

I created a button, but receive an `Error End of statement expected` error.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

X = TextBox1.Text
Y = TextBox2.Text

If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then Z = X + Y  End IF

If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then Z = X - Y End IF

If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then Z = X * Y End IF

If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then Z = X / Y End IF

TextBox3.Text = Z
```

Comment: Its pretty unclear what are you trying to ask.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: I have 2 variables TextBox, 4 Radio Button, A Button "Calculate"

Comment: when I click calculate, the operator is applied to the two values X, Y

Answer (score 1):

When writing **single line If** statements, you don't have to put `End If`.
That's why it's complaining that `End of statement expected.`

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code (so long as it is properly formatted in your IDE; the formatting in the question is wrong).

Just for fun, I switched some things up for you. You might try something like this to make your code more readable:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    X = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
    Y = CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
    Select Case True
        Case RadioButton1.Checked
            TextBox3.Text = X + Y
        Case RadioButton2.Checked
            TextBox3.Text = X - Y
        Case RadioButton3.Checked
            TextBox3.Text = X * Y
        Case RadioButton4.Checked
            TextBox3.Text = X / Y
    End Select
```